# ** Don't have a product spec for: 'lineage_klte'

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

It's been a while since i've done any android source builds (about 3 years) and this is what i'm running into no matter what device I try to build for. I've already extracted the proprietary blobs and downloaded all the proper repos such as devices, kernel, etc..

source build/envsetup.sh
breakfast klte or breakfast and choose a device by number

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 92
Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/klte
Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/klte-common
Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/msm8974-common
Looking for dependencies in device/qcom/common
Dependencies file not found, bailing out.
Looking for dependencies in device/samsung/qcom-common
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [dump-many-vars] Error 1

** Don't have a product spec for: 'lineage_klte'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?

The /bin/bash stuff has me a little confused as well, not even sure where to look to correct those two lines.

As far as the product spec?? I have all the right stuff in all the right places but still no go?? I remember having this issues some years ago while building CM12 for another device but that was ages ago and I can't remember what the fix was.